# STRLEN in PHP something's wrong

Tags: php

just a quick question regarding STRLEN in php... below is my code where I believe somewhere is wrong but just don't know where..

what im trying to do (obviously) is to show error message if there is less than 2 (excluding 2) characters in each of the text boxes..

WHen i run this, it's doing absolutely nothing so there must be something wrong with it.

Any help definitely appreciated!!

```
 $error_message = "";
        if(strlen($username) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The username you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
        if(strlen($start) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The start time you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
        if(strlen($end) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The end time you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
        if(strlen($location) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The location you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
        if(strlen($department) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The department you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
      if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
      }
```

Comment: `2 or less` is `<= 2`

Comment: Is died a typo? The PHP function is `die`.

Comment: _"WHen i run this, it's doing absolutely nothing so there must be something wrong with it."_ - so start debugging. Do an `echo strlen($username)` for example.

Comment: Where do those variables come from?

Comment: it comes from text boxes in the same form

Comment: excuse me that was my problem i forgot to add a ; after the echo.
i added that ; and its now working, but its still not working: no error message is showing up. so the validation still isnt working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 or less means you need to do:

```
if(strlen($variable) <= 2)
```

What you are doing is less than 2 which excludes 2 (1 or less)

Comment: thanks for your comment. what i meant was less than 2. I essentially just dont want the user to leave blank box haha

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what value you are getting in strlen($username),strlen($department),...
What is the error you are getting ?

New Edit

Try to add else ,this will make you sure that code is readed .

```
 if(strlen($username) < 2) {echo "The username you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />";}
else {echo "username is present";}
```

Comment: im not getting a single error message. it's just not doing anything.

Comment: i used echo debugging as per a commentor said above, and it showed me this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\emergency\Assign_form.php on line 119

Comment: You must have echo without ';' . Please paste the echo statement and teh result of echo

Comment: yeah i realised that, after adding that ; it works, but its not working. the validation still isnt doing anything. its not showing me any error message if i leave a box blank

Answer (score 0):

best approach is to use something like

```
if(isset($username{3}) ... ) {
    ....
  }
...
```

there is simple reason to use $var_name{IndexOf} because its faster then strlen and indirectly it is also checking weather its greater then 2